# After Effects vector animations

Tags: animation, after-effects

I need to make loading animation from the logo. Logo is: a circle of beads made from circles of different sizes. About 12 pieces as it falls out of the total circumference. Logo in the format .ai. I am creating a ilustrator separated layers for each drop-down circle and open in after effects. 
I do so, create a new composition, import ai file, add to composition and open the transformation options, change x and y guides in new keyframe, but nothing.
How do I create animation for these vector objects?

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge , u  cant change the details of the ai files in after effects .You can only work those files in the composition.So the most probable animation would be using the scale option .

Answer (score 0):

You turn the Ai layers into the shape layers and then go on from there.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the layer in the compositing and choose "convert to layered comp". This will import each .ai layer as a new after effects layer. From there you can animate all you want!

Alternately you can click "create shapes from vector layer" which will convert it to shape layers. This can be advantageous for more complex animations, but if you just need position I would go with the above solution.